# f:ajax and jquery's `$(document).ajaxStart` dont work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf-2

I'm trying to get a 'loading' div for my ajaxified website.
using JSF 2.0's `f:ajax` tag for adding ajax to the website and 'trying' to make the loadin `div` show using `jQuery` `$(document).ajaxStart` function.

The jQuery code part looks like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    console.log("ajax start");
  $('#ajaxBusy').show(); 
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    console.log("ajax end");
  $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
});
```

The log functions are never called.
Any Idea why? Do JSF ajax and javascript ajax not work together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(callback)` to display a loading div. Maybe `addOnError` too.

See the [**documentation**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html)

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(statusUpdate);
...
var statusUpdate = function statusUpdate(data) {
...
}
```

You will need to work with `data.status`

- `begin`: before the request is sent
- `complete`: request recieved
- `success`: request succesfully processed (without errors)

Examples using this api:

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/10/19/request-aggregation-jsf-2-ajax
- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/05/jsf_2_ajax_even.html

Answer (score 1):

The shorthand `$` can be the problem if using jsf, component libraries and jquery.

Try to call jQuery this way:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's correct.  Different JSF implementations may use different AJAX engines, and the jQuery ajaxStart/ajaxStop only apply to those components that route AJAX requests through the jQuery $.ajax function.

In contrast, if you're using Primefaces, the jQuery ajaxStart/ajaxStop events *will* fire and the jsf.ajax.onEvent *will not* fire.